# Breadth First Search vs Depth First Search

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Can anybody give a simple explanation on BFS and DFS?
I want to understand when to prefer BFS over DFS.

Answer (score 2):

BFS and DFS are both graph traversing algorithms, the difference between them is the way each algorithm traverses the graph.

**DFS**, Imagine you have the following graph and we want to start traversing from node `1`:

```
          1
         / \
        2   3
       / \   \
      4   5   6
```

DFS means **Depth** first search, so it will traverse the graph in this way:

- start from node `1` then look for its children. It finds node `2`.
- go to node `2` then look for its children. It finds node `4`.
- go to node `4` then it finds that it has no children.
- go `Up` to node `2` again and see its other children. It finds node `5`.
- go to node `5` then it find that it has no children.
- go up again to node `2` and find out that it has no more children.
- go up to node `1` then look for its children. It finds node `3`.
- go to node `3` then look for its children. It find node `6`.
- go to node `6` and find out that it has no children.
- go up to node `3` and find out that it has no more children.
- go up to node `1` and find out that it has no more children, hence the graph traversal has finished at this point.

If you note here how this algorithm goes in **depth** first, so once it found that node `2` is a child of node `1` it went for it and started looking for its children without caring about the rest of children of node `1` (node `3`) at this point of time, then after going to deepest possible node (nodes `4`, `5`) it started to go `Up` looking for the rest of children of node `1`.

On the other hand, consider we want to traverse the same graph using **BFS** algorithm. When using **BFS** you start thinking of graph nodes as levels, each level is closer than the level after it relative to the node you start traversing from. which means:

```
          1         (level 0)
         / \
        2   3       (level 1)
       / \   \
      4   5   6     (level 2)
```

So traversing the graph will be:

- start from node `1` then look for its children (nodes `2`, `3`) [the next level].
- traverse nodes of level 1 (`2`, `3`) and look for their children (nodes `4`, `5`, `6`) [the next level].
- traverse nodes of level 2 (`4`, `5`, `6`) and look for this children (no children) [no next level].
- then graph traversal ends at this point.

You can realize here that the direct children of a node (the next level) are always the closest nodes to it, and hence the advantage of using BFS over DFS is that it can guarantee for you that you reach from node `x` to node `y` using the shortest path possible.

But be aware that BFS algorithm can't find you the shortest path for all types of graph. The graph I mentioned in this example is unweighted graph (a graph in which all edges/paths are the same). If your graph is weighted (edges/paths have weights and not the same) then you have to use another algorithm that takes this into consideration (like [Dijkstra](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/)).

Comment: @ybnsl the best way to say thanks is described in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I'd also suggest removing the new part of the question you added on the end, as it risks making the question "too broad" (each question should only ask one question). And it wont take much thought to work out which of these two approaches will be a bad approach for.a web crawler.